# Equivalent to a DTD for microformats?

Tags: templates, editor, microformats

Is there any standard for defining the structure of microformats?

(I'm thinking about writing a tool for editing microformats within a WYSIWYG editor, using forms generated on the fly - so need an abstract grammar for describing individual migroformats).

I saw [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/describing_microformats_in_javascript) which seems to describe what I'm looking for - but are there definitions available in this format for the commonly used microformats?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: The most common microformats all have [XMDP profiles](http://microformats.org/wiki/profile-uris), but those are only readable by software at the "this text says what this means" level, not the "this means that" level. For fuller machine-readability, you probably want [GRDDL profiles](http://microformats.org/wiki/grddl), which map microformats directly to RDF. Fewer microformats have those, and the ones that do exist are years old, so don't cover newer changes to microformats.

Answer (score 0):

Microformats are developed by community, so there is no strict standardization. Existing microformats mostly were created at the [microformats.org](http://microformats.org), there you can find specifications. Some others ([unAPI](http://unapi.info/) or [COinS](http://ocoins.info/) for example) were developed elsewhere.

As a side node, I recommend to consider [Microdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML5%29) and [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/) because of their growing popularity.